# How do I execute a stored procedure on linked Firebird server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, firebird, linked-server

I have a linked Firebird database on my SQL Server 2008 via ODBC.

I can execute a query like this and I get the wanted results:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME')
```

Now i wonder how can I execute stored procedure with one parameter input.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME 00001')
```

and

```
EXEC LINKED_SERVER_NAME.STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME '00001'
```

with no success...

Any tip would be appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know in MSSQL but you can try

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'SELECT * FROM STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME(00001)')
```